# Sumar 30 días a partir de una fecha y mostrar el resultado en otro input

Tags: javascript

Buen día,

Tengo un formulario en el cual a partir de una fecha se debe de sumar 30 días habiles y en otro input mostrar la fecha de termino.

Estas son mis dos textbox:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fechadereservacion, new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fechadereservacion, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control datapicker" } })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaCierre, new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FechaCierre, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datapicker" } })
            </div>
```

Y este es el script para agregar los días:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sumarDias(fecha, dias) {
        fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);
        return fecha;
    }
    var d = new Date("#Fechadereservacion");
    console.log(sumarDias(d, 30))
</script>
```

Sin embargo no obtengo el resultado de tal suma.

Agradecería mucho de sus comentarios para poder mejorar la estructura y obtener lo que requiero.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar un ejemplo? Yo veo bien tu código, ¿qué es lo que esperas o qué es lo que está mal con tu código?

Comment: Pues lo que espero, es que cuando ingreso la fecha de reservación se sume 30 días, y en el textbox de fecha de cierre ya me muestre el resultado y al guardar el registro en mi vista se guarden los datos. Espero poder darme a entender un poco mejor.

Comment: Sí, eso queda claro, pero ¿qué valor pones y cuál es la salida? ¿Podrías poner un [mcve] por favor? He tomado tu código JS y probado con un valor "06/09/2022" y la salida  es el 09 de julio de este año, ¿no es lo que esperabas?

Comment: @ricardo-dlc Lo que me comentas de que probaste el código, el resultado que obtuviste es el que espero, sin embargo en mi caso dentro del formulario realizo el registro, y las fechas las tengo que poner manualmente. Como resultado me obtengo el mensaje de registro exitoso, por eso no puse la captura del error porque no me da excepción alguna.

Comment: Es que eso no lo has mencionado inicialmente (lo del registro), aparte de que no mencionas que framework usas para los formularios. Si "simplificamos" el tema de los formularios, aún así debería seguir funcionando el código que tienes. ¿Podrías simplicar tu formulario a HTML puro? ¿Te serviría?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para efectos de prueba añadí un eventListener para cuando se cambia la fecha.

Primero, para obtener el valor de la fecha de reservacion tienes que obtener el elemento por su id, luego le asignamos el valor a la variable "d".
Luego para dar el valor al input que contiene la fecha de cierre tambien vamos a buscar el elemento por su id, y asignamos mediante sumarDias, si bien queda la parte de convertir los formatos de fecha, esto depende de que tipo de "datepicker" estas usando.

Dejo un codepen con el ejemplo en html puro: [Ejemplo](https://codepen.io/sonryp/pen/BaYGabd)

```
<script>    
function sumarDias(fecha, dias) {
    fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);
    return fecha;
}
var x = document.getElementById("Fechadereservacion");
    x.addEventListener("change", function(){
         var d = new Date(x.value); 
         var y = document.getElementById("FechaCierre");
             y.value = sumarDias(d,30);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios, me ayudo mucho tu aportación, probé tu ejemplo con lo que tengo y me funciono. Adicional con lo que tenía me faltaba agregar la función de getElementById y llamar cada uno de los nombres de mis textbox de fecha como Id.                                                                           
Nuevamente gracias @Sonry